# Spread operator in the auth-workflow example

Tags: react-router

Trying to get an async auth request (axios) to work within react-router. Ive been using react-router synchronously for a while and I understand the render function variant, but in this component from the auth-workflow example [1]:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
      <Component {...props}/>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    )
  )}/>
)
```

what is the spread operator `...rest` supposed to expand to and/or return? I assume it's an async/restful call of some sort but I don't understand its place in the Route statement above at all (second line). Is it supposed to return a path? A promise? Or simply update the auth state somehow asynchronously (e.g. set `isAuthenticated` in the next line)?

Suggestions and pointers to docs appreciated!

Edit: looks like it's just a generic list of the rest of the props. I think I was overthinking it?

[1] https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow